# no such file or directory when using execv()

Tags: c, shell, execv

Im trying to write a basic shell that can interpret simple commands like date, ls in the language c.

I start by getting the PATH variable like this to later pass it on to the execv() function.

```
const char *name = "PATH";
char *value;
value = getenv(name)
```

and i print out the value and i get this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Note that i am using virutalbox to run Ubuntu. And this is the code that i am using to try a simple ls command. In the code below the variable line is the actual command that the user wrote, in our case it is "ls"

```
  pid_t pid, wpid;
  int status;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
      // Child process
      if (execv(value, line) == -1) {
          perror("lsh");
      }
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (pid < 0) {
        // Error forking
        perror("lsh");
  }
  else {
      // Parent process
      do {
          wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
      }
      while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    }
```

And the result i get is this:

```
lsh: no such file or directory
```

any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's `lsh`?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? @EugeneSh.

Comment: I mean it looks weird that you have chosen to run some "opensource SSH protocol implementation project" according to Wiki.

Comment: As a side note, you most likely want `_exit` not `exit` after a failed `exec`* call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`execv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html) system call uses the name you specify in the first argument as the file name of the executable; it does not do a PATH-based search.

That means that if you specify `"lsh"` as the first argument, there must be an executable file `lsh` in the current directory.

If you want a PATH-based search, replace `execv()` with `execvp()`.  Otherwise, specify the pathname — absolute or relative, but absolute is more normal — of the command in the first argument.

Note that if any of the `exec*()` functions returns, it has failed.  There's no need to test the return value; it will always be -1.

The contents of `value` and `line` need to be along the lines of:

```
char *value = "ls";
char *line[] = { "ls", "-l", 0 };

execvp(value, line);
```

or, more conventionally:

```
execvp(line[0], line);
```

If you are analyzing the PATH yourself, you'll need to have `line[0]` pointing at the complete file name that you've created from PATH, and then you use `execv()` instead of `execvp()`.

Comment: I tried changing it to execvp() but i get the same response. getenv() should work to get the pathname right?

Comment: @TimoCengiz: `getenv()` is largely immaterial.  It will get the current value of `PATH` if that's what you ask it for, but `execv()` won't use that.  Behind the scenes, `execvp()` will use `PATH` if the name in first argument has no slash in it.  It will then prefix the command with each element of PATH and try to execute that.  If you're converting `"ls"` to `"/bin/ls"` etc, you have to do the concatenation yourself.  If you use `execvp()`, if the first argument contains `"ls"`, then `execvp()` will find and execute the first `ls` executable found in a directory on the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `execv` is the command to run.  This means you're trying to run `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` as a command.

Assuming the first value in the `line` array is the program you want to call, you should instead do this:

```
execv(line[0], line);
```

And if you want to perform a path-based search, use `execvp` instead (no need to manually extract the PATH variable):

```
execvp(line[0], line);
```

EDIT:

For example, suppose you wanted to run `ls -l /usr/bin /var/log`, your array would look like this:

```
char *line[] = { "ls", "-l", "/usr/bin", "/var/log", NULL};
```

Comment: ok so i get that line[0] equals to "ls" but what is the second argument line in the execvp() function that you described?

Comment: @TimoCengiz The second argument is an array of `char *` which are the command line arguments.  Index 0 of this array contains the name of the command and it is what appears in `ps` listings.  The rest are the command line arguments, with the last element in the array being NULL.

Comment: Okay so i tried using execvp the way you mentioned. It worked i dont get any error message now but i dont get an answer to. Nothing basically happens. I can write another command and it does not matter what i write. I tried writing "sdfsdf" but it did not give me any errors?

Comment: @TimoCengiz Did you close either `stdin` or `stdout`?

Comment: no. So execvp(line[0], line) will print out the result if it's a success?(just to clarify)

Comment: @TimoCengiz Assuming `line[0]` can be found, `execvp` runs whatever it is.  Then whatever it outputs, success or fail, should be seen assuming you haven't messed with any open file descriptors.

Comment: @TimoCengiz A more complete code example would be required to see what's happening.